# Present Subview inside a UINavigationController from Keyboard Extension

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a keyboard extension and want the user to be able to tap on "settings", and be taken to the settings page inside the actual app.  I was pretty excited when I got that working, but I realized that the page wasn't inside the navigation controller anymore!

Here is my code.  How can I augment it to present a specific sub-screen inside my 'TransparentNavigationController'?

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    let urlPath : String = url.path as String!
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


    if(urlPath == "/inner"){

        let innerPage: myStampsVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myStampsVC") as! myStampsVC
        self.window?.rootViewController = innerPage
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

I've tried different mixes of

```
let navigationController = window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let innerPage = navigationController.viewControllers[4] as! myStampsVC
```

but I'm missing something.  Thanks for any nudges in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    let urlPath = url.path

    if(urlPath == "/inner"){
        func showMyStamps(in navigationController: UINavigationController) {
            navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
            _ = navigationController.topViewController?.view
            let innerViewController = myStampsVC() as UIViewController
            navigationController.pushViewController(innerViewController, animated: false)
        }

        switch window!.rootViewController {
        case let demo as DemoScreen:
            if let navC = demo.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController {
                showMyStamps(in: navC)
            } else {
                let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let navC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TransparentNavController") as! UINavigationController
                demo.present(navC, animated: false)
                showMyStamps(in: navC)
            }

        case let navC as UINavigationController:
            showMyStamps(in: navC)
        default: assertionFailure()
        }

    }
    return true
}
```